# Catalog REST API: Paging not working?

Tags: rest-api, magento2.3.1

I try to fetch all products in bunches from the REST API in Magento 2.3.1:

```
GET http://example.local/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=100&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=ASC&searchCriteria[currentPage]=88000
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer mybearer
```

I have 250 Products in the shop, still this request returns results. Shouldn't such a ridiculously high page number return an error or no results?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8099

Answer (score 1):

I my logic I was assuming, that Magento returns empty results in case the page is invalid / empty, so my script was fetching until $result['items'] is empty.

This is not the case.

So I changed my client like this:

```
if ($result['total_count'] < $result['search_criteria']['page_size'] * ($result['search_criteria']['current_page'] - 1)) {
    return null;
}
```

and bail out if `null` is returned.